# Why doesn't slidedown sometimes gracefully move the content below it?

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 buttons on a page with a hidden div underneath each. Each use the same jquery code to slideDown() the hidden object directly underneath. Both 'work' technically as in the outcome is the same, but the transition is very different.

The problem is that 1 slides all the content underneath the object nice and smooth like, while the other slides down the hidden stuff over the top of the content underneath - THEN once the slide is complete, all the content underneath snaps below it.

What would cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Can you show some code or create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kchpg/ - here's the thing. the fiddle works as expected :| there's something I can't seem to derive that must be different between the css somewhere or the layout causing the kind of irregularity I described in the question. i will try and add more to the fiddle to see if i can replicate the issue.

Comment: i find floats and positioning often account for content snapping.

Comment: yes, I think you are right zzzzBov... i've rectified the issue which definitely has something to do with floats and absolutes... but i still don't know what the defining element was that caused the problem.